# Using column value as clause for IN MySql

Tags: mysql

I don't understand why this doesn't work, I have a column where I store values comma separated in my "Mysql" database then I want to join two tables to give me results. eg:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u INNER JOIN
     groups g
     ON u.id IN ( g.ownerId )
WHERE u.active='1' AND g.gid='15';
```

And the value of `g.ownerId` in this senerio is '175,178'.

For some reason this only returns the results from the join with ownerId 175. BUT if I manually enter the values  ( 175, 178 ) in the IN clause BOTH rows show up. Why isn't it using both values in the ownerId column?

I have tried this to "separate" the values or force a "list" but it didn't work...
    SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN groups g ON u.id IN ( SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.ownerId, ',', 1), ' ', -1) as x,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.ownerId, ',', 2), ' ', -1) as y ) where g.groupId='15'

Has anyone experienced this before or know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the `in` value consists of a list with a single element that happens to have a comma in it.  It is equivalent to:

```
on uid = '175,178'
```

You can replace the logic with `find_in_set()`:

```
on find_in_set(uid, g.id) > 0
```

However, you really should learn about junctions tables and why your data structure is bad, bad, bad:

- You are storing numbers as strings.
- You have foreign key relationships with no way to declare them.
- You are using string operations inappropriately.
- Your query cannot make use of an index.

Fix the data structure.

Comment: I am not sure he stores numbers as strings. I saw it many times the field is numeric but the programmers use the quotes as it would be a string.

Comment: Yes, you hit the nail on the head Gordon, I was trying to avoid using a "junction table". But I see now for the reasons you laid out, it's the better way to go. Thanks!